# my result from using bcryptjs compare returns false. When comparing plaintext to hashed password from database (mongodb).(node-js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Unfortunately the result of the compare function is always false? Even when correct data is posted. Think it may have something to do with the compare function for bcrypt?

signup
hash and salt the password

```
 module.exports.signupPost = async (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
    //create a user with hashed password
            try {
        const newUser = await User.create({ email, password });
        newUser.password = await bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 12);
        newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json({ user: newUser._id });
    } catch (err) {
        errors = handlerErr(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
    };
```

login
compare the password to the hashed password

```
    module.exports.loginPost = async (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ email });
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).json({ email: "No user found" });
            }
//if user exist check password is a match
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ email: "No user found" });
    }
    try {
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(
            password.toString(),
            user.password,
            function (err, res) {
                console.log(res);// returns false
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {}
    };
```

```
user schema
```

database user schema

```
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Please enter a  email"],
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
            
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
            lowercase: true,
        },
    });
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove lowercase from the password mongo schema? I believe if you provide a password with capital letter, your implementation will convert them to lowercase before hashing, which means that when comparing they won’t match.

Comment: This seems to yield the desired result! @JBallin. Thank for the information as well it was truly insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `lowercase: true` from the password schema.

You’re converting the password to lowercase both before hashing it and when saving the hash.

---

You should allow capitalization in passwords by removing `lowercase: true` in your mongoose “password” schema. This setting causes all strings to be transformed to lowercase before being stored in the database.

The current implementation has 2 bugs:

1. When you save `newUser`, the input password gets converted to lowercase in the DB which you then use to generate the hash.
2. When you save the hashed password to the database, you lose capitalization and therefore the hash is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://openbase.com/js/bcrypt/documentation#to-hash-a-password-1), you must check the result through this way:

```
bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password); // result true or false
```

Comment: this function is in my login route no? My question is , even though i compare a plaintext password and hashed password within function. it returns undefined not true or false. This is the problem

Comment: @DevDub thats not possible, which version of bcrypt you are using. 
also what does ```console.log(bc.compareSync('', ''))``` prints to console.

Comment: @bogdanoff i have the bcryptjs 2.4.3. When i log the compare function it return nothing. the promise is pending, while request is hanging.

Comment: @DevDub something is wrong, it should not return promise. I just installed [`"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3"`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) and it prints `false` for ```console.log( bcrypt.compareSync("", "") )``` as  expected.

Comment: I recommend doing a clean install

Answer (score 0):

```
   const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Please enter a  email"],
            unique: true,
            lowercase:true,
        
            
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
           
        },
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).